# How to solve $h(t) = -16t^2 + 63t + 4 = 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The height $h$ of an arrow in feet is modeled by $h(t) = -16t^2 + 63t + 4$, where $t$ is the time in seconds since the arrow was shot. How long is the arrow in the air?

I don't get how to do this once its set up as $0 = -16t^2+63t+4$.

Comment: Well, what are some ways you know of solving quadratic equations?

Comment: was going to comment, a numerical exercisem with strange integers should suggest, as a first hypothesis, that it is an exercise in factorization of a quadratic polynomial, and its relation to toxophily is incidental

Comment: To be honest I cant remember how to do them

Comment: It'll help to write the equation with a negative sign in front of the 16t^2.

Comment: Yes, i forgot to put the negative. thanks.

Comment: @Desiree, minus signs are easy to forget.  Doing so can lead to unpleasant incorrect results.  In this case you might wind up concluding that the arrow never returns to earth!

Comment: Thats what my teacher tells me too... I tend to go thru it fast to get it done but then like you said leads to unpleasant in-corrections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an equation of the form $at^2 + bt + c = 0$ you can find the solution(s) with the quadratic formula:

$$t = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}.$$

Plugging and chugging:

$$t = \frac{-63 \pm \sqrt{63^2 - 4(-16)(4)}}{2(-16)} = \frac{-63 \pm 65}{-32} = \frac{2}{-32} \text{or} \frac{-128}{-32},$$

or $-1/16 \text{ or } 4$.  You probably want the positive one since you (presumably) shot the arrow at $t=0$.

Comment: thanks! (: okay so I would have t= -63 +-sqrt 63^2 - 4(-16)(4)/ 2(-16)

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: okay :) then once i solved that i ended up with t = -63+- sqrt -131.8... what would i do next?

Comment: @Desiree, careful, you should only take the square root of $63^2-4\cdot(-16)\cdot4=4225.$

Comment: oh yes i see.. okay then it would be t= -63+-sqrt 4219/2(-16)

Comment: Hmmmm ... The value I get for the square root is $\sqrt{4225} = 65$.  Something's off.

Comment: @Desiree, again, be careful.  The denominator divides the entire expression $-63\pm\sqrt{4225}$, not just the square root portion.  Also, it's $4225$, not $4219$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Comments are flying fast. :) I was looking at the $4219$.

Comment: your right it is not 4219.. i mutliplied it wrong so we have now t= -63+-sqrt 4225/2(-16)

Comment: @John thanks for the help! It makes sense now. So i was kind of on the right track :)

Comment: @BarryCipra thank you too! It makes more sense now. The formula is pretty easy I just need to take it slow and not rush so much (:

Comment: @Desiree, you're welcome.  I'm glad it makes sense now.  You're right, the formula is pretty easy once you get the hang of it.  It helps to pay attention to the types of mistakes you tend to make, so that you can learn to compensate for the tendencies.  Most mathematicians make plenty of them.  The great French mathematician Poincare once wrote, "As for myself, I must confess I am absolutely incapable of doing an addition sum without a mistake."  Good luck!